# document.querySelector for element inside bootstrap Popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to select element inside popover and create ajax get call on click. I am not able to select element in the first place.

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>2016-06-06</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Worker 1</td>
      <td id="worker1_date1">8h</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
$("#worker1_date1").popover({
    html: true,
    content:" <span>Task 1: 6h. Approved: False <button id='btn_worker1_date1' class='btn btn-success btn-sm'>Approve</button></span> <span>Task 2: 2h. Approved: True <button id='btn_worker1_date2' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'> Disapprove</button></span>",
});

// This works
document.querySelector("#worker1_date1").textContent = "Modified Text"

// This does not work
document.querySelector("#btn_worker1_date1").textContent = "Modified Text"
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mzw87oqv/1/

Comment: Inspecting that fiddle, the button id is `btn_worker1_date1` so `$("#btn_worker1_date1").click(...).` should be enough.

Comment: $("#btn_worker1_date1").click(function() {
 alert("Test");
});
It doesn't work :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The popover is adding its HTML to the DOM only when you click the element it's attached to. So when you run `document.querySelector("#btn_worker1_date1").textContent = "Modified Text"`, the element with ID `#btn_worker1_date1` does not exist on the DOM, and therefore cannot be changed.

You can solve this by listening to the event fired when the popover is shown.

```
popover.on('shown.bs.popover', () => {
   document.querySelector("#btn_worker1_date1").textContent = "Modified Text";
});
```

See [modified example](https://jsfiddle.net/x8qd7pnv/)